# C program to print all bits allocated for given variable, using Recursion

Tags: c, recursion, binary, bit

I was wondering what would a recursive function that prints all bits of the given variable (can be `char`, `int`, `long`, ...).

Since char allocates 8 bits for a variable, I need to print a total of 8 bits. For example, if the input is `5`, the function should print `00000101`.

I can only come up with iterative function for the same purpose, and it looks like this:

```
void print_bit_iter(char x, int n)
{
    int i, bit;
    for(i=n-1; i>=0; i--)
    {
        bit = (x & (1 << i)) != 0;
        printf("%d", bit);
    }
}
```

- The existing question doesn't print preceding zeroes...

Comment: There is one idea.

Comment: Since you want the most significant bits first, you call the function recursively (with `n-1`) and then print the `n`th bit.  The base case is `n == 0`, of course.

Comment: ofc that function doesn't handle leading zeroes...

Comment: @AnttiHaapala I have an answer but can not post it, because it is marked as a duplicate (mine is with leading zeroes). In my opinion, it is not a duplicate question.

Comment: I will post my answer at the duplicated question.